# Why does my J2ME DateField not display the correct date?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am storing values and date values in a record store.  I have my date field set up like this:

```
StartDate = new DateField("Start Date ", DateField.DATE);
                cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2009);
                cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
                cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                StartDate.setDate(cal1.getTime());
```

and I save the date as a string as follows:

```
 strStartDate = cal1.get(cal1.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                (cal1.get(cal1.MONTH) + 1) + "/" +
                cal1.get(cal1.YEAR);
 String detailsToAdd = strStartDate
```

(I have shortened the code.)  Now, I want to be able to edit the date at a future stage. However, I need the code to be able to do this. So far I have:

```
EStartDate = new DateField("Start Date ", DateField.DATE);
```

I had to change the name of the `DateField` box as this was conflicting with other things.

I basically need to be able to show the selected record's date attribute. I currently have the other information displayed. I just need to be able to show the correct date. When I run the program the date field says `<date>`.

Any help will be nice

Comment: The title for this question needs to be more specific than 'can someone help' in order for people  to be bothered to take a look.

Comment: This is the user's first question.  Be gentle.  I fixed the title.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code as followed is correct:

```
            StartDate = new DateField("Start Date ", DateField.DATE);
            cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2009);
            cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            StartDate.setDate(cal1.getTime());
```

But for the second one, you can't save date to String directly. You must convert it to String like this:

```
            String detailsToAdd =strStartDate.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the locale you are running in does not accept dates with **/** as a separator? I am sure there is a locale independent way to compose a date without using string concatenation as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet you provided doesn't use [setDate(Date)](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/DateField.html#setDate%28java.util.Date%29). If your actual code doesn't use it too, then `<date>` in the field is correct behavior - it tells you that date is "not initialized".

In that case, first smoke-test it with some simple code, like

```
    eStartDate = new DateField("Start Date ", DateField.DATE);
    eStartDate.setDate(new Date());
```

then, if that shows the date, learn how to recreate needed Date parameter from `strStartDate`. That is, recreate if you want user to be able to modify it - because if all you need is to display the date, it would be simpler to use `StringItem` displaying needed string instead